# Looking for great examples of web app changelogs

Tags: versioning, changelog

I've been working on a web app (in beta) for company for the past few months. Now that we're at the point of release, looking back, we should have had a better versioning system in place. We've got a ruleset in place for future releases, so I'm hoping that we can develop some better internal practices going forward.

What are some examples of web application (or desktop) changelogs that stand above the crowd?